# Gridview rowupdating event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am facing a very weird problem with `ASP.Net` `Gridview` in `Visual Studio 2013` and that is, when I click on `Update` link on my `gridview` in any row, I am not able to reset the grid. Please suggest if someone has faced this problem before.

I am more curious to know the same since this was working till yesterday and suddenly this stopped working. And all the other events are still working perfectly fine.

I have a `gridview` control on my `aspx` page with below header definition

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTeam" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
         AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
         OnRowEditing="tblTeam_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         OnRowUpdating="gvTeam_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvTeam_RowCancelingEdit"
         OnRowDataBound="gvTeam_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="member_id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZSName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZSLevel" HeaderText="Level" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Admin?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsAdmin" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIsAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsAdmin") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Office" HeaderText="Office" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdated" HeaderText="Last Updated" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsActive" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email Id" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Space Id" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="space_id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("space_id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And below is the code that I have written for row updating event

```
    protected void gvTeam_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
        gvTeam.EditIndex = -1;
        gvTeam.DataBind();

    }
```

Row Editing code below:

```
protected void tblTeam_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.NewEditIndex;
    //LoadTeamDetails();
    gvTeam.EditIndex = index;
    gvTeam.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: you can please show your gvTeam_RowEditing code

Comment: added the row editing code

Comment: change the code as bellow answer and let me know what new

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as bellow

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvTeam" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
         OnRowEditing="tblTeam_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         OnRowUpdating="gvTeam_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvTeam_RowCancelingEdit"
         OnRowDataBound="gvTeam_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="member_id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZSName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZSLevel" HeaderText="Level" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Admin?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsAdmin" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIsAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsAdmin") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Office" HeaderText="Office" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdated" HeaderText="Last Updated" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsActive" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email Id" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Space Id" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="space_id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("space_id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="btnupdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" CssClass="btncancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnedit" CssClass="btnedit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btndelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" Text="Delete"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work, but I have figured out the solution and it had to do with loading gridview on panel instead of page